# error: package com.google.gson does not exist, when automation scripts are run through maven Command line

Tags: java, maven, selenium, cucumber-java

I am using selenium with java and cucumber for my automation scripts and maven as build management tool. 
POM.xml has the dependency for 'gson':

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and my scripts run perfectly fine when it is run through Runner class feature by feature.

When i try to run all the tagged test Scenarios using the maven command line

```
mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @automated"
```

i get this error

> package com.google.gson does not exist

POM.xml has the required dependency. why is it not able to recognize the gson package?

Comment: "provided"
This is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime.

Comment: I have edited the question, "provided" was not added while running my automation script

Comment: mvn clean install ?

Comment: tried, now build is success but testscenarios tagged with '@automated' didn't get executed

Comment: same issue "error: package com.google.gson does not exist"